# Set of instances of sealed case object hierachy

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-cats

Imagine I have the following:

```
sealed trait MyEnum

object MyEnum {
  case object Value1 extends MyEnum
  case object Value2 extends MyEnum
  ...
}
```

I could fairly easily write a macro (its a few lines of code using `knownDirectSubclasses`) to give me the `Set[MyEnum]` of the `case object`s.

I'm sure this must have been solved already - perhaps there is something in **Shapeless** or **Cats** that will give me this set without me having to write the macro? - Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with [Enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum):

```
import enumeratum._
import scala.collection.immutable

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    sealed trait MyEnum extends EnumEntry

    object MyEnum extends Enum[MyEnum] {
      case object Value1 extends MyEnum
      case object Value2 extends MyEnum

      override def values: immutable.IndexedSeq[MyEnum] = findValues
    }

    val res: Set[MyEnum] = MyEnum.values.toSet
  }
}
```